# Bootstrap datepicker options with javascript append not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap `datepicker` on a form element that is appended to a div when another dropdown is selected. The `datepicker` is working, but I can't get the options to apply.

I'm not sure if this is a limitation with `datepicker` or I am doing something wrong. The html is just

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">

            <div id="dateSelector">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

the append block looks like this

```
dateSelector.append('<label class="control-label text-muted">Event date</label>' +
                                  '<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker-group" data-provide="datepicker">' +
                                  '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="event_date">' +
                                  '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
                                  '<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>' +
                                  '</span>' +
                                  '</div>');
```

with the options in the same js doc like this

```
    $('#datepicker-group').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  clearBtn: true
});
```

I've spent hours trying to work this out and can't see where I'm going wrong.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: _The datepicker is working, but I can't get the options to apply._ please try to clarify more what you mean, we can't see any options in your question and we don't know what you can't get them to apply!?

Comment: Try using the `data-date-format` and `data-date-clear-btn` attributes on datepicker-group instead. See https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#options

Comment: JsFiddle example would be better.

Comment: Hi @ZakariaAcharki the options are in the #datepicker-group block and they should change the way the date picker displays

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any syntax errors?

You selector looks suspicious. Try:

```
$('#dateSelector').append('....');
```

Comment: What is this ?! Who tell you `dateSelector` doesn't contain `$('#dateSelector')`. and he says the datepicker appended  and work fine _The datepicker is working_

Comment: Hi Kate, no errors, just no options applying to the datepicker. It’s showing US date format, but the options should be switching it to UK

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Travis, using the data-date-format and data-date-clear-btn attributes on datepicker-group worked. I had seen his in the bootstrap docs and tried it before without success, but I think I tried it in the input, not the div.

New .append now looks like this

```
              dateSelector.append('<label class="control-label text-muted">Event date</label>' +
                                  '<div class="input-group date" id="datepicker-group" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true">' +
                                  '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="event_date">' +
                                  '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
                                  '<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>' +
                                  '</span>' +
                                  '</div>');
```

Everything else the same.

Thanks!